# Regex to avoid whitespace at the beginning and at the end for angular 5

Tags: regex, angular

I am trying to generate regEx to avoid white spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string. But the white space between two words or characters should be allowed.

So far I have tried this -

`[^-\s][a-zA-Z\s]+[^-\s]$`

The issue in above regEx is that it doesn't allow space between two characters.

It only allows space between two words of size greater than 2.

Comment: Please provide some test cases with sample valid/invalid strings. Can there be more than 1 whitespace between words? Try `/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$/` or `/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$/`. Also, if it is used in an `ng-pattern`, add `ng-trim="false"`.

Comment: any feedback? Please provide the code that does not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Pattern `"^[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$"`

```css
input[type="text"]:valid{
background:green;
}
input[type="text"]:invalid{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*">
```

Comment: In an HTML5 pattern, you do not even need `^` and `$`, the pattern is anchored automatically. However, OP is writing the code in Angular, so this is hardly a solution. Note OP does not allow `-` and `_` in the original regex, why add these chars to allowed ones (in your code snippet)?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
/^[^ ][\w\W ]*[^ ]/
```